# Hyperledger Fabric - Error while Instantiating chaincode (error trying to connect to local peer: context deadline exceeded)

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm, hyperledger-chaincode

I am using **Hyperledger Fabric v 1.3.0** and trying to deploy using swarm network on multiple hosts. I am facing an issue when trying to instantiate the chaincode. The error i get is below in the image

Chaincode Instantiate Error :

[image]

I keep getting "Error trying to connect to local peer: context deadline exceeded"

From some discussions, i added these 2 environment variables in the peer yaml

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
```

But still i get the same error.

Any pointers regarding the same?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue before when the peer is trying to stand up a chaincode container on a different docker network to which the peer is on- I'd recommend that you check the network(s) that all the containers are running on across your hosts and ensure the peer/chaincode networks are aligned

Comment: Thanks but i have checked all of that. If the network is different, the error is clear and says that this network "abc" does not exist. Incidentally this is the same issue i am facing on a Kubernetes cluster as well.